# What is a condition for two real functions $f,g$ to "commute", so $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, real-numbers

Say I'm given two functions $f,g$. Can I tell if they "commute" without actually trying them in the formula
$f(g(x))=g(f(x))$?

And given a function $f$, is there a way to find all functions $g$ such that
$f(g(x))=g(f(x))$?

I've tried using derivatives and the chain rule but haven't got anything interesting yet.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but here are a few examples of pairs of commuting functions, which might  get you thinking.  ($r$ and $s$ are real   numbers throughout.)  (1) $f(x) = x^r, g(x) = x^s, f(g(x)) = g(f(x)) = x^{rs}$.  (2) $f(x) = rx, g(x) = sx, f(g(x)) = g(f(x)) = rsx$.  (3) $f(x) = x+r, g(x) = x+s, f(g(x)) = g(f(x)) = x+r+s$.

Comment: If $g$ is invertible, then $f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$ is equivalent to: $g^{-1}(f(g(x))) = f(x)$. This would suggest that $f$ and $g$ affine is sufficient, but as is clear from @MichaelLugo's comment above, not a necessary condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is, in general, no characterization other than the evaluation of $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$.

Also, for fixed $f$ there is no an easy way to find all the $g$ such that $f \circ g = g \circ f$.

Special cases can be studied. For example, a theorem of J. Lipiński says that if $f$ is a continuous and strictly monotonic function on an interval $I$ such that $f(I) \subseteq I$ then there is an infinity of solutions $g$ (depending on an arbitrary function).

Comment: Do you have the reference to the Lipiński's theorem?

Comment: Look at chapter X of Marek Kuczma, Functional Equations in a Single Variable.

Answer (score -1):

If $f(x) = g^{-1}(x)$, then $f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$ but the converse is not true.

If $f(x) = g(x)$, then $f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$.

Comment: This is incorrect. What about when $f(x) = x^{3}$ and $g(x) = x^{2}$? Surely $f(g(x))=g(f(x))=x^{6}$, but $f(x)$ is not equal to $g(x)$.

Comment: @Taylor Rendon, it is not incorrect. Note that this answer claims sufficient conditions, it doesn't claim them to be necessary.

Comment: @Ennar ah, I was just thinking about this and you beat me to it! Thank you for pointing that out.